# Log failed tesg case and continue with loop

Tags: java, automated-tests, logic, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am reading the test data from excel sheet and iterating the record.
On every iteration I am asserting the response in `restassured`.

Here is the code:

```
if (rbac == true && isallowed == var)
    System.out.println("Test case is pass because rbac status and allowed status are matched");
else if (rbac == false && isallowed == false) {
    assertEquals(403, response.statusCode());
    System.out.println("Test case is pass because rbac status and allowed status are matched (false)");
}
else if (rbac == false && isallowed == true) 
    Assert.fail("Test case fail because rbac status is false but allowed status is true.");
else
    Assert.fail("Test case fail");
```

Now I want

1. Pass and failure test cases record will get logged in report.
2. Test will continue if any record during test case will get failed until last record.

Comment: oh, please format your code, we cannot read this such messy code.

Comment: Consider using [Parameterized Tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests). That way each record becomes its own test case and will be reported independently from the other tests.